# Авторизация в ЕСИА через IE11

Tags: c#, авторизация, есиа

Не работает авторизации в ЕСИА чрез IE11, в других браузерах всё ок.
Проблема заключается в слишком длинном url.

Для получения авторизационного кода необходимо выполнить запрос
https://esia-portal1.test.gosuslugi.ru/aas/oauth2/ac
Ссылка должна содержать разные обязательные параметры, одним из которых является **client_secret**

Описание параметра из [методички](https://digital.gov.ru/ru/documents/6186/) 191 ст.

> <client_secret> – подпись запроса в формате PKCS#7 detached signature
> в кодировке UTF8 от значений четырех параметров HTTP–запроса: scope,
> timestamp, clientId, state (без разделителей). <client_secret> должен
> быть закодирован в формате base64 url safe. Используемый для проверки
> подписи сертификат должен быть предварительно зарегистрирован в ЕСИА и
> привязан к УЗ системы-клиента в ЕСИА. ЕСИА использует сертификаты в
> формате X.509 и взаимодействует с алгоритмами формирования электронной
> подписи ГОСТ Р 34.10-2012 и криптографического хэширования ГОСТ Р
> 34.11-2012

Так вот **client_secret** получается очень длинным (5 011 символов) и в IE11 запрос обрезается до 4 096 символов, поэтому и не работает авторизация.

Вот так выглядит [ссылка](https://esia.gosuslugi.ru/aas/oauth2/ac?client_id=MESO01017&scope=openid%20contacts%20gender%20fullname%20email%20usr_org&response_type=code&state=9b89a333-21ee-4849-8ebf-6f2556a8fc85&timestamp=2021.08.24%2017%3A12%3A08%20%2B0000&access_type=online&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fseti.midural.ru%2FLogin%2FProcessAuthorization&client_secret=MIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAqCAMIACAQExDjAMBggqhQMHAQECAgUAMIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAQAAoIAwggnrMIIJlqADAgECAhAB1tH54BqaMAAAAD8RwgABMAwGCCqFAwcBAQMCBQAwggGgMVswWQYDVQQDDFLQk9CR0KMg0KHQniAi0J7Qv9C10YDQsNGC0L7RgCDRjdC70LXQutGC0YDQvtC90L3QvtCz0L4g0L_RgNCw0LLQuNGC0LXQu9GM0YHRgtCy0LAiMVswWQYDVQQKDFLQk9CR0KMg0KHQniAi0J7Qv9C10YDQsNGC0L7RgCDRjdC70LXQutGC0YDQvtC90L3QvtCz0L4g0L_RgNCw0LLQuNGC0LXQu9GM0YHRgtCy0LAiMQswCQYDVQQGEwJSVTEzMDEGA1UECAwqNjYg0KHQstC10YDQtNC70L7QstGB0LrQsNGPINC-0LHQu9Cw0YHRgtGMMSEwHwYDVQQHDBjQldC60LDRgtC10YDQuNC90LHRg9GA0LMxGzAZBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWDHNkQGVnb3Y2Ni5ydTEsMCoGA1UECQwj0YPQuy4g0JHQvtC70YzRiNCw0LrQvtCy0LAsINC0LiAxMDUxGjAYBggqhQMDgQMBARIMMDA2NjcxMzUyMzYxMRgwFgYFKoUDZAESDTExMTY2NzEwMDUwODcwHhcNMjAxMjE0MDkxNjMyWhcNMjExMjE0MDkxNjMyWjCCAhsxOTA3BgNVBAMMMNCh0LzQuNGA0L3QvtCyINCd0LjQutC-0LvQsNC5INCR0L7RgNC40YHQvtCy0LjRhzF7MHkGA1UECgxy0JzQuNC90LjRgdGC0LXRgNGB0YLQstC-INGN0L3QtdGA0LPQtdGC0LjQutC4INC4INC20LjQu9C40YnQvdC-LdC60L7QvNC80YPQvdCw0LvRjNC90L7Qs9C-INGF0L7Qt9GP0LnRgdGC0LLQsCDQodCeMRcwFQYDVQQMDA7QnNC40L3QuNGB0YLRgDELMAkGA1UEBhMCUlUxMzAxBgNVBAgMKjY2INCh0LLQtdGA0LTQu9C-0LLRgdC60LDRjyDQvtCx0LvQsNGB0YLRjDEhMB8GA1UEBwwY0JXQutCw0YLQtdGA0LjQvdCx0YPRgNCzMSIwIAYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFhNtaW5lbmVyZ29AZWdvdjY2LnJ1MRcwFQYDVQQEDA7QodC80LjRgNC90L7QsjEqMCgGA1UEKgwh0J3QuNC60L7Qu9Cw0Lkg0JHQvtGA0LjRgdC-0LLQuNGHMSwwKgYDVQQJDCPQv9C7LiDQntC60YLRj9Cx0YDRjNGB0LrQsNGPLCDQtC4gMTEaMBgGCCqFAwOBAwEBEgwwMDY2NzAyMTQ0MDAxGDAWBgUqhQNkARINMTA4NjY3MDAxODA5MzEWMBQGBSqFA2QDEgswMjI3MDQ0NTAwOTBmMB8GCCqFAwcBAQEBMBMGByqFAwICJAAGCCqFAwcBAQICA0MABEBweeVzXkfgGfL9O2zA9Y4ji8qK9lUY6t2NeFL8Tm-l5mMN_7L41HJy2jJjZfNg4IoyGSynVA8AhuKLtUaFTQvkgQkAMTFDMjAwMDGjggUXMIIFEzALBgNVHQ8EBAMCA_gwOQYDVR0lBDIwMAYIKwYBBQUHAwIGCCsGAQUFBwMEBgYqhQNkAgEGCCqFAwUBGAIeBggqhQMFARgCBjAMBgNVHRMBAf8EAjAAMB0GA1UdDgQWBBR-lZs8iWXG1BzxpfTxjgL3s_l3DjAiBgUqhQNkbwQZDBfQodCa0JfQmCBWaVBOZXQgQ1NQIDQuMjCCAcMGBSqFA2RwBIIBuDCCAbQMgY7QodGA0LXQtNGB0YLQstC-INC60YDQuNC_0YLQvtCz0YDQsNGE0LjRh9C10YHQutC-0Lkg0LfQsNGJ0LjRgtGLINC40L3RhNC-0YDQvNCw0YbQuNC4ICJWaVBOZXQgQ1NQIDQuMiIgKNCy0LDRgNC40LDQvdGCINC40YHQv9C-0LvQvdC10L3QuNGPIDIpDG3Qn9GA0L7Qs9GA0LDQvNC80L3Ri9C5INC60L7QvNC_0LvQtdC60YEgIlZpUE5ldCDQo9C00L7RgdGC0L7QstC10YDRj9GO0YnQuNC5INGG0LXQvdGC0YAgNCAo0LLQtdGA0YHQuNGPIDQuNikiDFjQodC10YDRgtC40YTQuNC60LDRgiDRgdC-0L7RgtCy0LXRgtGB0YLQstC40Y8g4oSWINCh0KQvMTI0LTM0MzMg0L7RgiAwNi4wNy4yMDE4INCz0L7QtNCwDFjQodC10YDRgtC40YTQuNC60LDRgiDRgdC-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-UMWhggEspIIBKDCCASQxHjAcBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWD2RpdEBtaW5zdnlhei5ydTELMAkGA1UEBhMCUlUxGDAWBgNVBAgMDzc3INCc0L7RgdC60LLQsDEZMBcGA1UEBwwQ0LMuINCc0L7RgdC60LLQsDEuMCwGA1UECQwl0YPQu9C40YbQsCDQotCy0LXRgNGB0LrQsNGPLCDQtNC-0LwgNzEsMCoGA1UECgwj0JzQuNC90LrQvtC80YHQstGP0LfRjCDQoNC-0YHRgdC40LgxGDAWBgUqhQNkARINMTA0NzcwMjAyNjcwMTEaMBgGCCqFAwOBAwEBEgwwMDc3MTA0NzQzNzUxLDAqBgNVBAMMI9Cc0LjQvdC60L7QvNGB0LLRj9C30Ywg0KDQvtGB0YHQuNC4ggoQD-B4AAAAAAM4MB0GA1UdIAQWMBQwCAYGKoUDZHEBMAgGBiqFA2RxAjAMBggqhQMHAQEDAgUAA0EA1tcnxbaAMDc5U19h4j3SrJ6h6yYSp9RxLPjhrx9avGfwI7DC047ixW5FtioYKBQw06n1vYuedZSFNrMy6Koo1gAAMYIEfTCCBHkCAQEwggG2MIIBoDFbMFkGA1UEAwxS0JPQkdCjINCh0J4gItCe0L_QtdGA0LDRgtC-0YAg0Y3Qu9C10LrRgtGA0L7QvdC90L7Qs9C-INC_0YDQsNCy0LjRgtC10LvRjNGB0YLQstCwIjFbMFkGA1UECgxS0JPQkdCjINCh0J4gItCe0L_QtdGA0LDRgtC-0YAg0Y3Qu9C10LrRgtGA0L7QvdC90L7Qs9C-INC_0YDQsNCy0LjRgtC10LvRjNGB0YLQstCwIjELMAkGA1UEBhMCUlUxMzAxBgNVBAgMKjY2INCh0LLQtdGA0LTQu9C-0LLRgdC60LDRjyDQvtCx0LvQsNGB0YLRjDEhMB8GA1UEBwwY0JXQutCw0YLQtdGA0LjQvdCx0YPRgNCzMRswGQYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFgxzZEBlZ292NjYucnUxLDAqBgNVBAkMI9GD0LsuINCR0L7Qu9GM0YjQsNC60L7QstCwLCDQtC4gMTA1MRowGAYIKoUDA4EDAQESDDAwNjY3MTM1MjM2MTEYMBYGBSqFA2QBEg0xMTE2NjcxMDA1MDg3AhAB1tH54BqaMAAAAD8RwgABMAwGCCqFAwcBAQICBQCgggJcMBgGCSqGSIb3DQEJAzELBgkqhkiG9w0BBwEwLwYJKoZIhvcNAQkEMSIEIEwQB5NjVs4YpN-T5EoqXKYkfOPMOfWMdAxwUIZGWpCAMIICDQYLKoZIhvcNAQkQAi8xggH8MIIB-DCCAfQwggHwMAoGCCqFAwcBAQICBCAomZgcSY6UsQSMi0ToDpX1EK4iY7Xd_L8_CgnOdxVFVjCCAb4wggGopIIBpDCCAaAxWzBZBgNVBAMMUtCT0JHQoyDQodCeICLQntC_0LXRgNCw0YLQvtGAINGN0LvQtdC60YLRgNC-0L3QvdC-0LPQviDQv9GA0LDQstC40YLQtdC70YzRgdGC0LLQsCIxWzBZBgNVBAoMUtCT0JHQoyDQodCeICLQntC_0LXRgNCw0YLQvtGAINGN0LvQtdC60YLRgNC-0L3QvdC-0LPQviDQv9GA0LDQstC40YLQtdC70YzRgdGC0LLQsCIxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlJVMTMwMQYDVQQIDCo2NiDQodCy0LXRgNC00LvQvtCy0YHQutCw0Y8g0L7QsdC70LDRgdGC0YwxITAfBgNVBAcMGNCV0LrQsNGC0LXRgNC40L3QsdGD0YDQszEbMBkGCSqGSIb3DQEJARYMc2RAZWdvdjY2LnJ1MSwwKgYDVQQJDCPRg9C7LiDQkdC-0LvRjNGI0LDQutC-0LLQsCwg0LQuIDEwNTEaMBgGCCqFAwOBAwEBEgwwMDY2NzEzNTIzNjExGDAWBgUqhQNkARINMTExNjY3MTAwNTA4NwIQAdbR-eAamjAAAAA_EcIAATAKBggqhQMHAQEBAQRApBon6JNioEaixTR2kdbDDjtgWIRCZYB7dEmhPDtXM-T-ml1VMJ4fenmlR-n1A8K5CuyI_tsa3nh5po_dT7NdyAAAAAAAAA2), которая потом обрезается.

P.S.
Пытался обратиться в тех. поддержку ЕСИА, но не нашёл куда.

Comment: Наколько я помню, эти настройки ограничений IE может тянуть из реестра, есть 2 настройки - общая длина урла и длина секции урла. Точно где оно лежит и как называется - не припомню, но копать куда-то туда. В идеале конечно лучше всего дропнуть IE 11 из требований к реализации и забыть про него как про страшный сон. Он уже давно мертв.

Comment: [The Internet Explorer 11 desktop application will be retired and go out of support on June 15, 2022. For a list of what’s in scope, see the FAQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/missing-internet-explorer-maintenance-settings-for-ie11).

Comment: @aepot Дропним в будущих контрактах, а вот текущие договорённости надо поддерживать.
Посмотрю еще раз в сторону увелечения размера url., но насколько помню она не конфигурируется.

Comment: Она точно конфигурируется, я только не знаю, имеет ли это отношение к MSIE. `но насколько помню она не конфигурируется` тогда и ответа на ваш вопрос нет.

Comment: @aepot Думал может как-то можно передать client_secret  в POST запросе или может еще что-то дельное придёт кому-то на ум. В гос. услугах нет такой проблемы, но там и нет подобного запроса где нужно передавать client_secret.